# Python thread-safe access without blocking or uncontrolled queue growth?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a hardware sensor.  I need to continuously read the sensor and perform some math on the prior 3 seconds worth of readings.  (The faster I read, the more samples I have, the better my result, so I want to continuously call my function.)  I need to provide the user (via a web call) the current result at the time of the request.  Results may change significantly on a sub-second basis.  The user may request an update as fast as possible or very infrequently.

I currently have the following code, which works.

```
from threading import Thread
from MySensorReadAndMath import MySensorReadAndMath

class ManageSensor(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.result={}
        self.mySensorReadAndMath = MySensorReadAndMath()
    def updateResult(self):
        result = {}
        result['value1'] = self.mySensorReadAndMath.value1
        result['value2'] = self.mySensorReadAndMath.value2
        return result
    def getResult(self):
        return self.result
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.mySensorReadAndMath.update()
            self.result = self.updateResult()
```

In a separate piece of code, I create the class, use Flask to create a web call to *ManageSensor.getResult()* to return the result, and start the thread.

Is this thread-safe?  (Could I get the current *value1* and prior *value2*, or a corrupt *self.result*?) If it is not thread-safe, how would I make it thread-safe without ever blocking?

Specific things I have considered:

1. Do I get any benefit by first copying the values into a local *result* in *updateResults()* (compared to directly putting everything directly into *self.result* in  *updateResult()*
2. If I put locks around updating *self.result*, then my *run()* loop or my *getResult()* may block which I don't want.
3. If I push the result onto a queue within *run()* and pop it within *getResult()*, I will have issues with the queue size since I will never call *getResult()* as fast as *self.mySensorReadAndMath.update()* runs.
4. Am I over-thinking this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would try to use the built-in Queue class, but this situation may be too complicated for this.

If I understand correctly, you need to store exactly three seconds worth of data, regardless of the number of requests made by the user. You can solve this problem by making use of the fact that Python always accesses objects through references. Assigning a reference is an atomic action in Python, so you can safely use a singleton to store the latest result. There are two conditions:

1. There must be no assignments to members of the result after it has been published
2. The users of the result must retrieve the results once and only once during a request: if the results are retrieved a second time, the result will probably have changed.

So use a singleton to enforce this behaviour:

```
class Buffer:
    ''' A simple buffer that stores exactly one value '''
    latest = None
    @staticmethod
    def onNewReading(*args, **kwds): # or any parameters one fancies
        # Pack the results in a single object and store it
        Result.latest = (args, kwds)
    @staticmethod
    def onUserRequest():
        return Result.latest
```

Writing a value is as follows:

```
def process():
    # Do the measurement
    # Do the calculation
    Buffer.onNewReading(data1, data2, etc)
```

Using the value:

```
def handleRequest():
    results = Buffer.onUserRequest()
    # Format a response, using the results
    if not results:
        return 'No data available'  # or any other useful error message
    return response(results[0][0], results[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not thread safe.

The client thread could call getResult while updateResult is running, so result could be empty, half filled or contain old values.

Making another object and assigning it to result afterwards will limit the possibility of half filled data so this is a plus.

The queue solution would also require some kind of locking